# How to compare datetime.time objects

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a column in my Dataframe that contains datetime.time() values.
example :

```
--> df.loc[0,'tat']
output: datetime.time(0, 21, 4)
```

I want to write multiple if conditions with this column.
example:

```
--> if df.loc[0,'tat'] < 2:
     df.loc[0,'SLA'] = 'less than 2 hour SLA'
    else:
     df.loc[0,'SLA'] = 'greater than 2 hour SLA'

--> if df.loc[0,'tat'] < 4 and df.loc[0,'tat'] > 2:
     df.loc[0,'SLA'] = '2-4 hour SLA'
    else:
     df.loc[0,'SLA'] = 'greater than 4 hour SLA'
```

When I compare df.loc[r,'tat']< 2 it gives a **TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.time' and 'int'**

I then tried to create timedeltas.

```
timedelta_2 = timedelta(hours=2)
df.loc[r,'tat']< timedelta_2
```

It still gives me a **TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.timedelta'**

How else am I supposed to compare ?!

Answer (score 3):

You need compare hours with scalars, solution for new helper column `hour` with [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

```
hours = pd.to_datetime(df['tat'].astype(str)).dt.hour

hours = df['tat'].apply(lambda x: x.hour)

df['SLA'] = pd.cut(hours, bins=[0,2,3,24], 
                  labels=['less than 2 hour SLA','2-4 hour SLA','greater than 4 hour SLA'])
```

Or you can extract `hour` from `datetime.time` objects:

```
if df.loc[0,'tat'].hour < 2:
     df.loc[0,'SLA'] = 'less than 2 hour SLA'
elif (df.loc[0,'tat'].hour < 4) and (df.loc[0,'tat'].hour > 2):
     df.loc[0,'SLA'] = '2-4 hour SLA'
else:
     df.loc[0,'SLA'] = 'greater than 4 hour SLA'
```

Solution for new column `SLA`:

```
def func(x):

    if x.hour < 2:
         return 'less than 2 hour SLA'
    elif (x.hour < 4) and (x.hour > 2):
        return '2-4 hour SLA'
    else:
         return 'greater than 4 hour SLA'

df['SLA'] = df['tat'].apply(func)
```

Comment: But I do not want to change types. df['tat'] has values like 1hr 23 mins 45 seconds. I just want to compare this time and check if it's less than 2 hours. Similarly, if the df['tat'] value is 2hr 0 min 1 sec, I want to be able to say that it's greater than 2 hrs but less than 4 hrs.

Comment: So `tat` is `1hr 23 mins 45 seconds`not `datetime.time` ?

Comment: it is datetime.time. By 1hr 23 mins 45 secs I meant datetime.time(1, 23, 45)

Comment: Edited answer working for you?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare a datetime.time instance with an integer 
what you are doing is compaing apples with oranages 
i would suggest converting the int to a time instance

```
import datetime.datetime as dt
if df.loc[0,'tat'] < dt.time(hours=2,minutes=0,seconds=0):
    df.loc[0,'SLA'] = 'less than 2 hour SLA'
else:
    df.loc[0,'SLA'] = 'greater than 2 hour SLA'

if df.loc[0,'tat'] < dt.time(4,0,0) and df.loc[0,'tat'] > dt.time(hours=2,minutes=0,seconds=0):
    df.loc[0,'SLA'] = '2-4 hour SLA'
else:
    df.loc[0,'SLA'] = 'greater than 4 hour SLA'
```

I would also suggest that you make sure both the columns ('tat', 'SLA') are of datetime.time instance

Comment: df.loc[0,'tat'] < dt.time(hours=2,minutes=0,seconds=0) gives TypeError: unbound method datetime.time() needs an argument

Answer (score 0):

Datetime.time object represents time independent from the day. E.g.

```
datetime.time(0, 21, 4)
```

Translates to 00:21:04 AM

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#date-objects

So what you probably need is something to compare the 'tat' time to, in other words another datetime.time object e.g.

```
if df.loc[0,'tat']-other_datetime_time_object < timedelta(hours=2):
```

Or if 'tat' is actually representing duration of something, it should be timedelta object instead.

EDIT: If you cannot change the object type, the dirtiest hack would be to compare it to 00:00:00 hrs, e.g.

```
if df.loc[0,'tat']-datetime.time(0,0,0) < timedelta(hours=2):
```

Comment: the dirtiest hack is giving a TypeError: descriptor 'time' for 'datetime.datetime' objects doesn't apply to a 'int' object